# Spring Data JPA table join creating operator does not exist error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables, `Projects` and `TransitionAction`. Both `Projects` and `TransitionAction` have a column `request_no` which is used perform join between them. The entity classes are as below:-

Project.java

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id 
@SequenceGenerator(schema = "public", name="project_id_seq_gen",sequenceName="project_id_seq",initialValue=1,allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="project_id_seq_gen")   
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "request_no")
private String request_no;
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@Column(name = "department")
private String department;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "requestNo")
private Set<TransitionAction> tacts;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
private Status status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "level_id")
private ProjectLevel level;
```

TransitionAction.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transitionaction")
public class TransitionAction implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    @Column(name = "request_no")
    private String request_no;

    @Column(name = "actionDate")
    private Date actionDate;
```

The code used to retrieve the list of projects as follows:-

```
public interface UserInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInfo, Long> {

UserInfo findByUserName(String userName);

@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project Join project.tacts pta where project.request_no= pta.request_no and project.status.id=1")
List<Project> getAllUserProjects();
}
```

I am getting could not extract ResultSet error. When I checked console, i found the following query being generated:

```
select
        distinct project0_.id as id1_1_,
        project0_.department as departme2_1_,
        project0_.level_id as level_id6_1_,
        project0_.user_nodal_officer as user_nod3_1_,
        project0_.request_no as request_4_1_,
        project0_.status_id as status_i7_1_,
        project0_.title as title5_1_ 
    from
        project project0_ 
    inner join
        transitionaction tacts1_ 
            on project0_.id=tacts1_.request_no
```

I am not getting why project. id is joined with tact.request_no and creating the error

> Operator does not exist: integer = character varying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get all TransitionAction linked to Project by requestNo

You can achieve this by 
adding `@ManyToOne` Mapping in `TransactionAction` like this

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Project project;
```

Now you need to modify your query like this

```
@Query("SELECT project FROM Project project where project.status.id=1")
List<Project> getAllUserProjects();
```

To get all `TransactionAction` for a given project

```
Set<TransitionAction> allTatcts =  project.getTacts();
```

You dont need to add join in query. Hibernate will take care of that once you pull TransactionAction from Project by an entity.

**Edit 1:**

> But why did my query fail ? Why primary key of project joined with
>   request_no of TransitionAction ?

Your query failed because while doing `@OneTOMany` relation yodidn'tnt define `@JoinColumn or @JoinTable` which is a unidirectional mapping.

In this case, Hibernate will use primarykey column to map.

And since type of primarykey and column is different thus the error.

> Without describing any physical mapping (no @JoinColumn or
>   @JoinTable), a unidirectional one to many with join table is used. The
>   table name is the concatenation of the owner table name, _, and the
>   other side table name. The foreign key name(s) referencing the owner
>   table is the concatenation of the owner table, _, and the owner
>   primary key column(s) name. The foreign key name(s) referencing the
>   other side is the concatenation of the owner property name, _, and the
>   other side primary key column(s) name. A unique constraint is added to
>   the foreign key referencing the other side table to reflect the one to
>   many.

Refer [Official doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-one-to-many-with-join-table) for more detail

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="table_name",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="columnname")
)
private Set<TransitionAction> tacts;
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. But why did my query fail ? Why primary key of project joined with request_no of TransitionAction ? Please explain

Comment: I have answered your questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are having @Id on request_no in your TransactionAction class and when you join two class then they join on primary keys.

You can use cross join instead.

```
SELECT project FROM Project project, TransactionAction pta where project.request_no= pta.request_no and project.status.id=1
```

Or you can have bidirectional mapping. Add the following in your TransactionAction entity class.

```
@ManyToOne
private Project Project;
```

And then your query will be as follows.

```
select pta.project from TransactionAction pta where pta.request_no=pta.project.request_no and pta.project.status.id=1
```